# Rendering the field name in an EditorTemplate (rendered through EditorFor())

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, editorfor

I'm currently building the Admin back-end for a website in ASP.NET MVC.

In an ASP.NET MVC application, I've started using the 'EditorFor' helper method like so:

```
<div id="content-edit" class="data-form">
    <p>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(c => c.Title) %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Title)%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= Html.LabelFor(c => c.Biography) %>
        <%= Html.EditorFor(c => c. Biography)%>
    </p>
</div>
```

In the model, the 'Biography' field has been decorated with: [UIHelper("Html")].

I have an 'Html' partial view (under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.XML.Linq.XElement>" %>

<textarea class="html">
    <%= Model.ToString() %>
</textarea>
```

Now I'd like to have the 'ID' attribute of the 'textarea' set to the name of the field, like this:

```
<textarea id="Biography" class="html">
    ...
</textarea>
```

But I can't see a way to do that with the current set up.

All I can think of is creating an 'Html' ViewModel that contains a 'Value' property and a 'ControlID' property.

But if I based the view off that, rather than 'System.XML.Linq.XElement', it would no longer be compatible with the 'EditorFor' helper method and I'd have to do everything manually.

Has anyone had a similar problem yet?

Comment: Just found a similar question being asked by @nathan-taylor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329148/asp-net-mvc-solution-layout-suggestions

Comment: That question doesn't appear to have anything to do with this one.  Did you paste the wrong link?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to pull out the desired ID from the ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix property of the view.  Like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"
      Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.XML.Linq.XElement>" %>
<textarea id="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>" class="html">
    <%= Model.ToString() %>
</textarea>
```

To show why this works, here's the place in TemplateHelpers.cs (of MVC2 Preview 1 source) where ViewData is initialized for the Editor template control:

```
ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(html.ViewDataContainer.ViewData) {
    Model = modelValue,
    TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo {
        FormattedModelValue = formattedModelValue,
        ModelType = modelType,
        HtmlFieldPrefix = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(expression),
        IsNullableValueType = (underlyingNullableType != null),
    }
};
```

In the call above, "expression" is initialized (further up the call stack) with the name of the property being edited.

BTW, @Sperling below caught a detail I originally missed: if you're using (or might use) a non-default `HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement`, then you'll want to replace the dots in the `HtmlPrefix` property with `HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement`.

Comment: This is not a valid solution in the case of nested collection model. In that case ```HtmlFieldPrefix``` returns ```collectionModel[index].{PropertyName}``` but by default MVC creates id in a format ```collectionModel_{index}__{PropertyName}```. So it is safe to use ```ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)``` instead of  ```HtmlFieldPrefix```

Answer (score 4):

Have been using this to generate id(with model prefix). Skip the .Replace() part if
you want the name attribute.

```
<%=Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(String.Empty).Replace(".", HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement) %>
```

Comment: this works too, but you don't actually need GetFullHtmlFieldId-- if you look at that method's implementation, if its argument is String.Empty, it simply returns the value of the HtmlFieldPrefix property.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we had to use `Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName` with `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText`

which in razor was used like this:

```
           // hiddenFor was caching the value of this html input, and the value alone, nothing else on the page!
            Expression<Func<Web.ViewModels.ApiSettingsViewModel, int>> expression = (m => m.OrgApiLoginCredentials[i].OrgApiLoginId); 
        }
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.OrgApiLoginCredentials[i].OrgApiLoginId" name="@Html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression))" class="data-org-api-login-id"/>
```