# Render label for a field inside ASP.NET MVC 2 editor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I'm starting to use DataAnnotations in ASP.NET MVC and strongly typed template helpers.

Now I have this in my views (`Snippet` is my custom type, `Created` is DateTime):

```
 <tr>
  <td><%= Html.LabelFor(f => Model.Snippet.Created) %>:</td>
  <td><%= Html.EditorFor(f => Model.Snippet.Created)%></td>
 </tr>
```

The editor template for DateTime is like this:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>
 <%=Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("g"))%>
```

But now  I want to put inside editor template the whole `<tr>`, so I'd like to have just this in my view:

```
 <%= Html.EditorFor(f => Model.Snippet.Created)%>
```

And something like this in editor template, but I don't know how to render `for` for label attribute, it should be `Snippet_Created` for my example, the same as id\name for textbox, so pseudo code:

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>
 <tr>
  <td><label for="<What to place here???>"><%=ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName %></label></td>
  <td><%=Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("g"))%></td>
 </tr>
```

The `Html.TextBox()` have the first parameter empty and id\name for textbox is generated corectly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one solution here: [Rendering the field name in an EditorTemplate (rendered through EditorFor())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482925/rendering-the-field-name-in-an-editortemplate-rendered-through-editorfor)

But it seems a little verbose, may be it can be wrapped in custom Html Helper:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime>" %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="
            <%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix.Replace(
                    ".", 
                    HtmlHelper.IdAttributeDotReplacement) 
            %>">
            <%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName %>:
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("g")) %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName`

Comment: I have complex type (`Snippet.Created`) from my example. This property gives me only `Created`

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach using master pages:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html