# ASP.NET GetFullHtmlFieldId not returning valid id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

In MVC2 template, I normally use `this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(fieldName)`
to generate the id field of an html element. This has worked in most of the cases.

However this method does not actually return [valid id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482925/rendering-the-field-name-in-an-editortemplate-rendered-through-editorfor), it merely prefix `fieldName` with `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`, this is causing problems for me when rendering collections which has `[]` in the HtmlFieldPrefix.

I have been manually converting those characters to `_` where I find the need, but this seems to be not elegant (repeated code), has anyone found a good way to generate id field properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you be more specific about the kind of problems do you have?

For example, there is an elegant approach to [editing variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) with [validation support](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) provided. While it doesn't use templates still remains DRY with partial views.

While the ids are inconsistent - the names are OK and only problem I encountered is that using jquery.infieldlabel it appeared that label's for attribute (generated by GetFullHtmlFieldId inside LabelFor helper) didn't match id of the appropriate TextBoxFor input. So I created LabelForCollectionItem helper method that just uses the same method for id generation as the TextBox - `TagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName)`

Maybe the code doesn't correspond to your need but hope it will help somebody since I found your question among the first searching for solution to my problem.

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates Label with "for" attribute corresponding to the id rendered by input (e.g. TextBoxFor), 
    /// for the case when input is a collection item (full name contains []).
    /// GetFullHtmlFieldId works incorrect inside Html.BeginCollectionItem due to brackets presense.
    /// This method copies TextBox's id generation.
    /// </summary>
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelForCollectionItem<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
               string labelText = null, object htmlAttributes = null) where TModel : class
    {
        var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)); // to convert an object into an IDictionary

        // set inner text
        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string innerText = labelText ?? GetDefaultLabelText(html, expression, htmlFieldName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }
        tag.SetInnerText(innerText);

        // set for attribute
        string forId = GenerateTextBoxId(tag, html, htmlFieldName);
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", forId);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracted from System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions
    /// </summary>
    private static string GenerateTextBoxId<TModel>(TagBuilder tagBuilder, HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string htmlFieldName)
    {
        string fullName = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName);
        tagBuilder.GenerateId(fullName);
        string forId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
        tagBuilder.Attributes.Remove("id");
        return forId;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extracted from System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions
    /// </summary>
    private static string GetDefaultLabelText<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string htmlFieldName)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        return labelText;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your method, what happens if htmlFieldName contains square brackets? e.g. "Users[0]"

Comment: Html.LabelForCollectionItem(x => x.Users[0].Name) returns
<label for="Users_0__Name" ...

Comment: This is an interesting way to do it, helped me to come up with a solution for our specific situation. Thanks! (I'd up vote your answer if you can edit it -- so get around silly stackoverflow rules)