# How EditorFor set ID and Name html attributes on form elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have few layers of nesting custom user controls:

RegisterUser.aspx

```
 <%@ .... Inherit="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RegisterUserViewModel>"
 ...
 <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details) %>
 ...
```

UserDetails.ascx

```
 <%@ .... Inherit="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<UserDetails>"
 ...
 <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.BirthDate) %> <!--BirthDate is of type DateTime-->
 ...
```

and I have declared DateTime.ascx in Shared/EditorTemplates

```
 <%@ .... Inherit="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>"
 ...
 <input type="text" id="???" />
 ...
```

The question is how to set input id attribute? I know that EditorFor makes some magic for default types. For example if DateTime was of type string, EditorFor will set id of input type to "Details_BirthDate" and the name attribute to "Details.BirthDate". I want to know how it's done? Because I want to use it for my special custom types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using the following two methods:

```
<%= Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("BirthDate") %>

<%= Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("BirthDate") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

How many levels of editor templates are you going to use? I really think the last one is redundant and you could use:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate) %>
```

By the way there's [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) which is great. It has things like:

```
<%: Html.IdFor(x => x.BirthDate) %>
```

and:

```
<%: Html.NameFor(x => x.BirthDate) %>
```

which is really useful in some scenarios.

---

UPDATE:

Always use strongly typed editor templates:

```
<%@ .... Inherit="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>"
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x) %>
```

Comment: the last layer - Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate) - is not redundant because i want to make it fully custom, like datepicker and etc. So I really want to use custom control for the last layer

Comment: See my update about using a strongly typed editor template for DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix. Example:

```
<input type="text" id="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>">
```

You can use GetFullHtmlFieldId if you need to specify a field, but if it's used in a Display or Editor Template you can just use HtmlFieldPrefix.

More info in this SO question: [Rendering the field name in an EditorTemplate (rendered through EditorFor())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482925/rendering-the-field-name-in-an-editortemplate-rendered-through-editorfor)