# Validation for fax number only?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the following validation for fax numbers:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\+[0-9]{1,3}\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{7}$", ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid fax number.")]
```

But the fax number form entry does not accept any input.

Comment: Please provide sample input :). Anyway, you can try your regex in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244572/dataannotations-validation-regular-expression-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-view

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
\+[0-9]{1,3}\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{7}
```

Sample outputs;

```
+895(194)6165163
+09(155)2541778
```

You don't need to use `^` for this. It means "except".

Comment: Thanks for help. But My Client Said :The fax number form entry does not accept any input, including valid fax numbers, instead displaying 'this is not a valid fax number'

Comment: @sandeepsinghwarring then you should use js for this

Comment: @sandeepsinghwarring I don't understand what you said.. Please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

```
^[01]?[- .]?\(?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$
```

Try this........