# How to add real time validation in textbox MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance

I create MVC project, and 
I have table tblEmp stucture like this :

```
Id          int
Name        nvarchar
NIK         int
Point       numeric(18,2)
JointDate   date
```

In view create page, i want NIK field can only input by integer with maximum length 3 digit real time [not until i press button "create"], how i can solve this issue with the simple way ?
Need your help, please. thanks

Comment: Check with `MaxLengthAttribute` in MVC 5 or use RegularExpression `DataAnnotation` in mvc

Comment: Start here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation

Comment: Better http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started

Comment: @Murali, `MaxLengthAttribute` worked when i press button "Create" submited, and not when i press key in that NIK textbox. Is i need is when i pressed the keys in NIK textbox, it directly protected with integer value and max value = 3 digit, example = 123

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataAnnotations to ensure that the allowed values are from 0-9 and that it is only 3 digits long.

Then wire up jQuery Validator on your view and you will have what you need, real time validation.

See the following for RegularExpressions Data Annotations (NOTE: you will need to figure out the Regular Expression for your case)
[DataAnnotations validation (Regular Expression) in asp.net mvc 4 - razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244572/dataannotations-validation-regular-expression-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-view)

Comment: yes i already use DataAnnotation as you suggested to me, plus combined with jquery, it will work for me.