# Validate model on specific string values

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a Web API 2 project. besides the requirement that some properties are required, some only can have specific values. 
One option is that I could try to save the model to the database (EF6) and create some logic while saving, but I think it is better to validate if the correct value is set before I make a call to the database. Does data annotations provide an attribute like Range but then for specific string values like in the example below? Or do I have to write my own validator attribute?

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringRange("M","F")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, when a post is done to the controller, the only values to accept are "M" or "F".

Comment: You can use RegExes see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244572/dataannotations-validation-regular-expression-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-view

Comment: you can also create custom validation attribute https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcX8WW4fL1s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To validate the Gender property I've created a custom validation attribute by creating a new class (attribute):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;    

namespace MyProject.Models.Validation
{

    public class StringRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            if(value.ToString() == "M" || value.ToString() == "F")
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }


            return new ValidationResult("Please enter a correct value");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 47):

In case anyone stumbles upon this thread in the future, I took it a little further and added a public string array property accepting the allowable values in the validation filter. This will allow you to provide a collection of valid strings in the attribute decorator.

This way, you now have a generic reusable attribute you can use anytime to limit a model string property to a predefined set of values. Since it's a validation attribute, you can decorate it with a more informative error message as well.

Example Usage:

```
public class Person {
    [StringRange(AllowableValues = new[] { "M", "F" }, ErrorMessage = "Gender must be either 'M' or 'F'.")]
    public string Gender { get;set; }
}
```

String Attribute:

```
public class StringRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] AllowableValues { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (AllowableValues?.Contains(value?.ToString()) == true)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        var msg = $"Please enter one of the allowable values: {string.Join(", ", (AllowableValues ?? new string[] { "No allowable values found" }))}.";
        return new ValidationResult(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: For AllowableValues?.Contains() I had better luck with AllowableValues?.Any(). I love this solution, Simon!

Comment: ErrorMessage defined in the attribute is ignored and instead the content of msg variable is displayed when you do not enter any of the allowable values.

Answer (score 12):

you can use reqular expression like this:

```
[RegularExpression("M|F", ErrorMessage = "The Gender must be either 'M' or 'F' only.")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

but in my api it will show error message when i passed data 
so you can add

```
[StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "The Gender must be 1 characters.")]
```

final code:

```
[StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "The Gender must be 1 characters.")]
[RegularExpression("M|F", ErrorMessage = "The Gender must be either 'M' or 'F' only.")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```

Comment: Nice.  Quick 'n' dirty, and ideal for my present project!

Comment: What else if you have passed m|f. It will get failed. What need to add in lower case two get it pass ?

Answer (score 5):

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("value1|value2|value3|...", ErrorMessage = "YourMessageHere")]
public string Gender { get; set; }
```