# How to specify set of valid string values for a property?

Tags: .net-core, data-annotations

I have a class:

```
public class Product
    public Guid Guid {get;set;}  
   
    [Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

I want to specify what values are legal values for property `Brand`, for instance `"Audi,BMW,Mercedes"`.
Is that is possible to do without custom validator?

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987119/validate-model-on-specific-string-values, is it applicable for your case?

Comment: They use custom validator, maybe there is nothing built in like this.

Comment: RegularExpressionAttribute is not custom validator, is it?

Comment: You_are_right__