# C# DataAnnotations RegularExpression for Password Strength

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

All,

I am using `ASP.NET MVC` and trying to do a Regular Expression to enforce Password requirements.

**Register.cshtml:**

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Passwd, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
```

**Model Class:**

```
    [RegularExpression("/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8}/g", 
         ErrorMessage = "Password must meet requirements")]
    public string Passwd { get; set; }
```

I copied out the RegEx and tested it standalone in RegexPal.com and it worked perfectly.

However, when using it in my ASP.NET MVC app, I get the error message every time (even using Passwords that I know meet the requirements.

Am I doing something wrong?  Does the DataAttributes RegularExpression Attribute behave differently than standard RegEx?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244572/dataannotations-validation-regular-expression-in-asp-net-mvc-4-razor-view) post might guide you to some extent.

Answer (score 8):

You could try the following

```
   [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Password must meet requirements")]
    public string Passwd { get; set; }
```

If you also want to require at least one special character, try this:

```
   [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Password must meet requirements")]
    public string Passwd { get; set; }
```